# How to mount Amazon S3 bucket to a directory on FreeBSD?

Tags: mount, freebsd, amazon-s3

I can't find a solution on how to mount an Amazon S3 bucket to an existing directory on FreeBSD.
I suspect, I need to install port `fusefs-s3fs`.

But how should I configure it? I can't find any info.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you are right, you need to install fusefs-s3fs, once you have done that, make sure you put fusefs_enable="YES" somewhere in your /etc/rc.conf (so that fuse will start after a reboot).

Now create a file in /etc/ called passwd-s3fs and set its perms to 640.  In that file add your S3 access-key and secret key as follows:

```
accessKeyId:secretAccessKey
```

on a line all by iteself.

Then start fuse by executing /usr/local/etc/rc.d/fusefs start

and then you should be good to go, and you will be able to mount your S3 bucket as follows:

```
s3fs mybucket /mnt -ouse_cache=/tmp
```

All this of course, assumes that you are running as root.

If you need more information on using fusefs-s3fs, head over to http://code.google.com/p/s3fs/wiki/FuseOverAmazon